# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter

I have updated Jmeter 5.4.3 and added MySQL connect java-8.0.27 to bin folder also
and given JDBC Driver class as-com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
with all details. but when I run getting "Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USDxK.png)

Comment: Please check the logs of JMeter for the actual exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put the MySQL Connector/J to **"lib"** folder of your JMeter installation, not "bin" or to any other location which is in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). Also JMeter restart will be required to pick up the .jar
2. I believe correct class is [`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html)
3. Your image is incomplete so I cannot comment on other "all details".

More information: [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection)